# Why is a variable declared in onBeforeMount() not known in the main section of <script>?

Tags: vue.js, scope, vuejs3

I have a Vue3 component in which I use a pre-mount hook (this is a trimmed-down version to scope it to the problem):

```
<script setup lang="ts">

const hello = () => {
  let a = [... allNotes.value]
}

onBeforeMount(() => {
  let allNotes = ref([])
}

</script>
```

With this, I get a `ReferenceError: allNotes is not defined` on the line that defines a.

Why is it so? Isn't `allNotes` known to `hello()` after the mount?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you defining a reactive variable from inside a lifecycle hook? If you want `allNotes` to be available in the component or in the rest of your script, you only need to declare it in the top level of `<script setup>`. Remember that the Composition API `setup()` function replaces the `beforeCreate` and `created` lifecycle hooks, so anything defined within `setup()` will be available everywhere. You can read more about that in the [Vue Docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-lifecycle-hooks.html)

Specifically the problem here is that `allNotes` is scoped to the `onBeforeMount()` function only, and as such isn't known to the rest of your script. Once `onBeforeMount()` is called and finished, it will destroy `allNotes` and it will no longer exist.

You can just do

```js
<script setup>
  const allNotes = ref([])

  const hello = () => {
    allNotes.value.push("Hello")
  }
</script>
```

To illustrate the point with the OptionsAPI, what you're doing is the same as something like this:

```js
export default {
  beforeMount() {
    const allNotes = [];
  },
  methods: {
    hello() {
      this.allNotes.push("Hello!");
    }
  }
}
```

That won't work, since `allNotes` only exists inside of the `beforeMount()` hook. You'd have to declare `allNotes` in the `data()` or `computed()` properties in order for your `hello()` method to be able to use it.

Also, as a small sidenote, you should declare reactive elements with `const` and not `let`. It's a bit weird because you technically are changing its value, but the Vue internals make it so you're actually changing a *copy* of it that exists inside of Vue. As such, you're not actually modifying the original value, so `let` is inappropriate.

Comment: Small side node regarding the last paragraph: With a ref you internally create a Proxy object which should be a const. Inside this object you can still change the values, you just can't assign anything new to this const or you'll use the ref.

Comment: Thanks. In retrospect, the scoping is obvious as this is a function.